# Highscore only prints 0 python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

My highscore.txt always reads as zero and I cant figure out why. Can anyone help me with this?

```
try:
    File = open("Highscore.txt", "r+")
    File.write(str(uScore))
    for x in File:
        print(x)
    File.close()
except FileNotFoundError:
    File = open("Highscore.txt", "w+")
    File.write(str(uScore))
    for x in File:
        print(x)
    File.close()
```

Comment: Can you give more context and your code? Where does the `uScore` variable come from

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.  Your posted code fails to run.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be an issue with how you're writing to the file, but the value of uScore could equal 0.

Try printing out uScore before writing to the file, and make sure it's not 0.

Answer (score 0):

When you open a file for `"r+"`, the file pointer is at the beginning, so `File.write(str(uScore))` will overwrite the first score.

What you probably want is to open the file for append (`a+`), write the score to the end, then rewind the file to the beginning and read all the scores. You'll also need to write a separator, for instance a newline, so you can tell where each of the scores ends.

```py
    File = open("Highscore.txt", "a+")
    File.write(str(uScore) + '\n')
    File.seek(0)
    for x in File:
        print(x)
    File.close()
```

In addition, it's good style to (a) use lower-case letters for variables, and (b) use the `with` statement to ensure that the file is always closed:

```py
    with open("Highscore.txt", "a+") as f:
        f.write(str(u_score) + '\n')
        f.seek(0)
        for x in f:
            print(x)
```